# Constructor expecting missing call to other constructor / candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided?

Tags: c++, function, constructor, candidate

You may have seen my post yesterday about the issues I had been having with my text-based adventure game. I got all of that fixed up and added some functionality, but in adding some inventory arrays of custom Slot objects my Character object decided to stop recognizing their initialization.

Here's the basic code:

**Character Class**

```
class Character {
    InvSlot inventory[30];
    FoodSlot foodInv[10];
    //Declaring armor slots, class, race, stats, etc

public:
    //All of the function declarations
```

**Character Constructor**

```
Character::Character() :
    //Initializing armor slots, class, race, stats, etc to default values
{
    InvSlot inventory[30] = {emptyInv,...,emptyInv}; //The other 28 values are omitted here.
    FoodSlot foodInv[10] = {emptyFood,...,emptyFood}; //The other 8 values are omitted here.
}
```

**`InvSlot` and `FoodSlot` Structs w/ Basic Empty Slots**

```
struct InvSlot {
    bool isUsed;
    Item item;
    InvSlot(Item i);
};

struct FoodSlot {
    bool isUsed;
    Item item;
    FoodSlot(Food f);
};

InvSlot::InvSlot(Item i) : isUsed(false), item(i){}
InvSlot emptyInv = InvSlot(NoItem); //NoItem is a basic object of type Item which works

FoodSlot::FoodSlot(Food f) : isUsed(false, food(f), quantity(0){}
FoodSlot emptyFood = FoodSlot(NoFood); //Same deal with NoFood
```

**The Errors**

First of all, the struct declarations and constructor definitions for `InvSlot` and `FoodSlot` are giving me the issue of `candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided`. Second of all, the actual errors are on the final initializer in the `Character` constructor (before the curly braces): `no matching function for call to 'FoodSlot::FoodSlot()'` and `no matching function for call to 'InvSlot::InvSlot()'`. The thing is, I have already initialized the arrays in the curly braces and they aren't returning any errors themselves. On top of this, these two are the only two parameters for the character class which even use the `InvSlot` or `FoodSlot` objects. Can anybody help figure out what's going on, and how to fix it? I already checked other similar questions but they didn't help. Let me know if I need to add anything or if I missed something when typing up this post.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The line `InvSlot inventory[30] = {emptyInv,...,emptyInv}; ` doesn't do what you think. It is not initializing the `inventory` member. It's initializing a local variable that happens to have the same name. The member variable does not have any initialization, which means that the compiler tries to use default initialization, but it can't because there is no `InvSlot` constructor that takes 0 arguments.

Comment: @RaymondChen So how would I go about fixing it? I had already tried initializing it in the class declaration (keep in mind that in my code the declaration and definition are separated, in the `Character.h` and `Character.cpp` respectively) but it wouldn't let me because extended initializers are only supported by C++11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you get is basically that the default constructor can't be found, which is obviously the case. When you write

```
InvSlot inventory[30];
FoodSlot foodInv[10];
```

the default constructor is called to initialize your arrays. What you can do is to write a default constructor for `InvSlot` and `FoodSlot` which basically return an empty `InvSlot` and `FoodSlot`. With empty I mean the semantically equivalent of the objects you used in your initializer list (emptyInv, emptyFood).

Comment: Thanks! Added those default constructors and everything worked great. :)

Answer (score 0):

The sequence of what is currently happening:

1. (somewhere in `main`) Attempt to create an instance of `Character`.
2. `Character` is creating all of its data members: `inventory` and `foodInv`.
3. Since `inventory` is an array the constructor needs to be called 30 times, and it needs to be called before the execution of the constructor of `Character`. Because you don't provide the compiler with anything to call specifically, it will attempt to call the default constructor. And since you have defined parameterised constructor, the default has been deleted.

What you need:

**Option1**

in your header file:

```
class Character {
    InvSlot inventory[30] = {emptyInv,...,emptyInv};
    FoodSlot foodInv[10] = {emptyFood,...,emptyFood};
```

This is probably not the best option, since you clutter the header.

**Option2**

In the definition of your constructor:

```
Character::Character()
  : inventory{{emptyInv,...,emptyInv}}, foodinv{{emptyFood,...,emptyFood}}
{
}
```

Funny thing is that you already have the `:` symbol in your constructor definition, meaning that you have first attempted the correct solution (or perhaps you were unaware of the meaning of that character). It is there specifically to call constructors on the fields.

Comment: For both, I'm not using C++11 so I can't use the extended initializer lists.

Comment: @RaskorProgramming You do realise it's 2017 now. There's been C++11, C++14 already. So you are at least 2 standards behind. I guess you can define default constructor for the `Inventory` class then... but why are you doing that?